# How to run node.js script from systemd service

Tags: node.js, linux, unix, raspberry-pi, systemd

I have a node.js script in my directory on my raspberry pi `/home/pi/my/app/here/app.js`

When I navigate using `cd my/app/here` and run `node app.js` my script executes without any problems. However, when I try to execute this script from a service in `systemd` I get an `code=exited, status=203/EXEC` error.

Here is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=App
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
ExecStart=/user/bin/node /home/pi/my/app/here/app.js
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/my/app/here
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is really my first time using systemd and most of what I have found has been through research online and other SO posts. So I am sure I am missing something pretty silly, but any help on getting my service to run would be much appreciated.

What am I missing here?

Comment: A typo in /user/bin/node

Comment: ugh it did end up being a typo... `/usr` instead of `/user`. Thank you!

Comment: From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Put a hash bang in the file

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

And just ensure the `x` bit is set.

Comment: It actually seemed to be a issue with me having `/user` which is a type and should be `/usr`. What does the hash bang do for the file?